# Explain a for until loop in Scala

Tags: scala

Below code prints 2,1

```
val n = 3                                       
val i = 3    

for {
  i <- 1 until n
  j <- 1 until i
} println(i+","+j)
```

Should it not print :

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

I view `j <- 1 until i` as in inner loop of the outer loop but this obviously is not the case according to the output ? Can explain how above loop behaves ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `i` in `println(i+","+j)` refers to the i bound in `i <- 1 until n` not the top-level definition `val i = 3`

Another thing to be aware of is that `1 until n` is the range `1..n-1`, not `1..n`. You should use `to` if you want to include the upper bound.

Answer (score 3):

- First iteration for x will be omitted because **y <- 1 until 1**
- Second iteration will print 2,1 because x = 2 and **y <- 1 until 2**

  ```
     ╔═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════════╗
     ║   Cycle   ║     x    ║     y     ║      print     ║     
     ╠═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
     ║     1     ║     1    ║     1     ║ omit iteration ║    
     ╠═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
     ║     2     ║     2    ║     1     ║     (2,1       ║    
     ╚═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════════╝
  ```